# How to embed images in a single HTML / PHP file?

Tags: php, html, image, png, embed

I am creating a lightweight, single-file database administration tool and I would like to bundle some small icons with it. What is the best way to embed images in a HTML/PHP file?

I know a method using PHP where I would call the same file with a GET parameter that would output hardcoded binary data with the correct header, but that seems a bit complicated.

Can I use something to pass the image directly in a CSS `background-image` declaration? This would allow me to utilize the CSS sprite technique.

Browser support isn't an issue here, so more exotic methods are welcome also.

**EDIT**

Does someone have a link/example to how to generate Data URL's properly with PHP? I'd figure `echo 'data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents('image.png'))` would suffice but I could be wrong.

Comment: yep, `base64_encode(file_get_contents())` is the way to go. You might `chunk_split()` it, but that isn't necessary.

Comment: By the way: IE6 and 7 don't support `data:` URIs, IE8 only to a maximum length of some bytes (forgot the exact value, but it's definitely too little to serve a medium sized image).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

A solution to embed an image directly in an HTML page would be to use the [data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

For instance, you could use some portion of HTML that looks like this :

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAABGdBTUEAALGP
C/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB9YGARc5KB0XV+IA
AAAddEVYdENvbW1lbnQAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIFRoZSBHSU1Q72QlbgAAAF1J
REFUGNO9zL0NglAAxPEfdLTs4BZM4DIO4C7OwQg2JoQ9LE1exdlYvBBeZ7jq
ch9//q1uH4TLzw4d6+ErXMMcXuHWxId3KOETnnXXV6MJpcq2MLaI97CER3N0
vr4MkhoXe0rZigAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

There are other solutions on the wikipedia page I linked to :

- including the image as a CSS rule
- Using some Javascript.

But note those solutions will not work on all browsers -- up to you to decide whether this is acceptable or not, in your specific situation.

**Edit :** to answer the question you asked about *"how to generate Data URL's properly with PHP"*, take a look a bit lower in the wikipedia page about the [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Inclusion_in_HTML_or_CSS_using_PHP), which gives this portion of code *(quoting)* :

```
function data_uri($file, $mime) 
{  
  $contents = file_get_contents($file);
  $base64   = base64_encode($contents); 
  return ('data:' . $mime . ';base64,' . $base64);
}
?>

<img src="<?php echo data_uri('elephant.png','image/png'); ?>" alt="An elephant" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

http://www.sveinbjorn.org/dataurls_css

Answer (score 0):

For one PHP server side script try a base64 encode of the graphic and use a simple controller-style logic:

```
<?
/* store image mime-type and data in script use base64 */
$images = array('photo.png' => array('mimetype' => 'image/png',
                                     'data' => '...'));
/* use request path, e.g. index.php/photo.png */
$action = substr($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], 1);
switch($action) {
case (preg_match('/\.png$/', $action)?$action:!$action):
  header("Content-Type: {$images[$action]['mimetype']}");
  /* use expires to limit re-requests on navigation */
  $expires = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', filetime(__FILE__) + 365*24*60*60);
  header("Expires: {$expires}");
  $data = base64_decode($images[$action]['data']);
  header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($data));
  echo $data;
  break;
...
}
?>
```