# Streaming HTML file along with images using java

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I have a HTML file which has images. I want read this file from local folder like C:/data using java and display it on browser along with images when request comes from client(other than localhost).

Comment: First I read HTML page and where ever i find `SRC` attributes in it I am replacing `src` value with absolute path (C:/data/img.png) but when i request from other machine this wont work...

Comment: it's normal that it won't work because the other machine doesn't know what is `C:/data/img.png` .what you have to do is when you find an src attribute is to copy the ressource from the C location to a folder behind your HTML let's call it images, so if your image is in images/img.png then set 'images/img.png' as the value of the src attribute.

Comment: Thanks.. but I have to stream the image along with HTML page but not to store them in a folder. Is there any way to do this..!?

Comment: you can do it by loading your images in a 64 encoding inside your HTML  check this to have an idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329364/how-to-embed-images-in-a-single-html-php-file

Comment: Thanks for the ref. Is there any way to implement this in JAVA..!? as I can see that its a PHP thing not java..

Comment: Hmm, unless you have a really complex structure, couldn't you simply use relative links ? `top` = top of your site

Comment: Why do you want the page and images to be directly under c rather than in the webapps folder under Tomcat (or whatever other servlet container)?

Comment: Thanq... but I have a plenty files and images to those, so saving them in server is not a good option @developerwjk

Comment: @Venkat, If they're to be served it makes more sense. And that way you know that nothing is served which is not in that area. Having things served from all over the server can open a security hole....