# C# - Add image in HTML using Stringbuilder

Tags: c#, html, winforms, stringbuilder

I am using Windows Form Application. The Software is Child Vaccination Scheduler, that needs Date of Birth of baby and prints due dates of required vaccines. I need to print data in Table form, for which I have used **StringBuilder** Class in which I have created table using **HTML**. That works fine.

Problem is I have to print **picture** of baby along with the **table**. I have used

```
<img src="image.jpg">
```

but it is not displaying any image in **C# output**.

How can i add Image in this HTML and C# Duo?

**Editted**

Code Snippet.

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.Append("//html data including table and image tag...");
webBrowser1.DocumentText = stringBuilder.ToString();
webBrowser1.ShowPrintDialog();
```

This is how my code looks excluding html table code.

Regards,

Mirza

Comment: You don't: The image "image.jpg" need to be in the same directory as the HTML file you (presumably) create; the *browser* loads & display it from that location.

Comment: all my html text is inside Stringbuilder object of c#. html is not a separate file.

Comment: But ultimately it will be displayed in a web browser? Thats where the image loading should take place.

Comment: As @AlexK. said previously you are looking for the image relative to the document. If possible could you specify the full URL to the image? i.e. `http://example.com/image.jpg`

Comment: Maybe use the [data URI scheme?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329364/how-to-embed-images-in-a-single-html-php-file/2329400#2329400)?  Doesn't work on all browsers though.

Comment: I have tried to place the image file where my code is as well as in debug/release folder, but got no image. I am not opening it in any browser. I want to print that image along with the table.

Comment: Ah, If you are going via the DOM like that try: `<img src="file://C:\wherever\the\image\is\image.jpg">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Code i used was something like this.

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.Append(
"<table>"+ 
"   <tr>"+
"       <td>Image: </td>"+
"       <td><img src='image.jpg"> </td>"+
"   </tr>"+
"</table>");
webBrowser1.DocumentText = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

The solution is, Relative path does not work in this case. Need to give absolute path for **src** in **image** tag like this .

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + image.jpg
```