# Displaying BLOB image from Mysql database into dynamic div in html

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a BLOB image that is stored when the user submits an advert form, they have the choice of uploading one image. The image is stored in the database with the other information.

Every time my page loads it dynamically creates the advert divs and also fills in the matching information from my database into the div.

The problem I have is displaying all the information including the image together at the same time so when the user clicks to view the page they see each div with a different picture and information. I've seen the other posts on how to display the image but I doubt its the same method when you're displaying several images from the same database.

My database is set up as follows:

ID
ADTITLE
EMAIL
PRICE
DESCRIPTION
CATEGORY
**name
type
size
content**
DATE

The bold variables are for the image/blob

Here is my code where I retrieve the information :

```
$Category = 'Specials'; 
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM adsubm WHERE CATEGORY LIKE '%$Category%' ORDER BY DATE DESC" );
$query->execute();

while($row = $query->fetch()) {
    $Adtitle=$row['ADTITLE'];
    $Desc=$row['DESCRIPTION'];
    $Price=$row['PRICE'];
    $Date=$row['DATE'];
    $timestamp=strtotime($Date);
    $Day= date("d",$timestamp);
    $Month=date("F",$timestamp);
    $Newmonth=date('M', strtotime($Month . '01'));
    $Year=date("Y",$timestamp);
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    $Image=$row['content'];


echo  " 
           <div class='[ col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 ]' style='margin-top: 10px'>
                <ul class='event-list'>
                    <li>
                        <time datetime='$Date'>
                            <span class='day'>$Day</span>
                            <span class='month'>$Newmonth</span>
                            <span class='year'>$Year</span>
                            <span class='time'>ALL DAY</span>
                        </time>
                        <img alt='#' src='$Image/>
                        <div class='info'>
                            <h2 class='title'>$Adtitle</h2>
                            <p class='desc'>$Desc</p>
                                                        <ul>
                                <li style='width:50%;'><span class='fa fa-money'></span>  $Price</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </li>
                              </ul>
                    </div>
        ";
```

My php skills are still beginner levels as well. I'm just trying to keep things as plain and simple as possible, i'll look into other methods abit later.

All help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: So your image is stored in db? Then have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329364/how-to-embed-images-in-a-single-html-php-file

Comment: @maxhb could I do this then : $Image = data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents('image.png')); then just echo that?

Comment: nah more `$Image = 'data:image/png;base64,'.$blob ;` where `$blob` is the image

Comment: AFAI understand $Image should contain the image file, so just do: echo 'data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($Image);

Comment: And remove header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

Comment: I did this $Displayimage="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($Image)";     And changed the <img scr='$Displayimage'> I got a whole lot of ëA™1œÓôU=GV³Òlåº½ºŽÖÚ1—š

Comment: @jamesmstone the $blob, what would I define that as? would it be a $blob =$row['content'];

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## 1) Base64 option

Work with a single line, `image/png` for a png image and `image/jpeg` for a jpg one :

```
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($blob).'"/>';
```

example :

```html
<div style="background-color:black; text-align:center; padding: 5px;">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAwBAMAAACh2TSJAAAALVBMVEUAAADtNTX////3n5/+9fX719f7zMz5tLTzfHzuQED//f31jY3ybGzxXV3wVFRaxp+rAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAALVJREFUOMut0rENAjEQRNHdC4kY0QBaAQUQX0QAFSAKIKQEKiAA6VqgIkriApuV1x7pQPz0aWwHljLMpZ0CRDBGoXmeghGYKFJsUo90giAImCgV5OJF+oOgKE48MlGgs2VLBIunWesw0a1ZHqF82c7GmmIfUSpgotOly29DFPFJFDEhkgIT/V5mZuvj6XofKrHU6vyI4u37IYi36aN4h5tL7PJyif1dvCgEpapzISbCTEj5R78BZq5A5Ldh2XYAAAAASUVORK5CYII">
</div>
```

---

## 2) Dedicated page

**With many big picture on the same page, the base64 may be not the good choice**

Base64 is cool, but **a bit heavy** (usually around **twice as the binary** value encoded) and **can't be cached** by the browser as it's a part of the page, and not a page by itself (like a picture).

In this case, the best is to use a specific php page to display your picture :

On the main page use instead of base 64 : `echo '<img src="image.php?id='.$id.'"/>';` with the id of the line you want the image.

On your `image.php`, for the basic you should use this :

```
// << include the $pdo here
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `content` FROM `adsubm` WHERE `id` = :id" );
$query->execute(array(':id'=>$_GET['id']));
$data = $query->fetch();

if(empty($data)))
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
else {
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    echo $data['content'];
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you! Good to see a working example, too.