# Converting imageview to base64 and storing it into mysql and how to decode it in Android

Tags: android, mysql, decode, encode

I have encoded the imageview using base64 and passed that value to textview as hidden as i have successfully inserted into db. my code to encode:

```
public void convertImg(){
    imageView.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bm = imageView.getDrawingCache();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b , Base64.DEFAULT);
    base64.setText(encodedImage);
}
```

This is what im getting in my mysql db. is it correct?
[image]
My question is how to decode it and where to see/view it?

Comment: Perhaps you are referring to server side decoding. Have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34112174/295004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image encoding looks right. To decode encoded string back to image you need to implement `BitmapFactory`.

First get bytes from the encoded string. Then use BitmapFactory to decode the byte array. `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` returns a bitmap that you then can use in an imageView.

```
byte[] b = Base64.decode(encodedString,Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b,0,b.length);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: can i write php code to decode and view it in my localhost web browser?

Comment: I personally don't know, take a quick look into [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15153931/6623419), you might find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you have to implement `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()` for decode your image base64 string have look this.

```
//decode base64 string to image
imageBytes = Base64.decode(encodedImage , Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
mage.setImageBitmap(decodedImage);
```

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: in the image what m getting by encoding, is it correct?

Comment: you will get view of image !

Comment: This may help http://codesfor.in/how-to-upload-image-to-server-as-base64-encoded-string/

Answer (score 0):

Since this was tagged Android I assume you're referring to sqlite?

Not a direct answer to your question but in sqlite you can store the binary blob without conversion to base64 first. It may be more efficient in your case since converting to/from base64 has a cost.

https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html