# Can't Display Longblob images with php in cpanel

Tags: php, mysql

```
$con= mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "database");  
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    //echo 'Hi! '.$_SESSION['username'];
}
if(isset($_GET["name"])){
    $n= "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_name`='".$_GET['name']."' "[0];
    $r= mysqli_query($con, $n);
    if($r){
        while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
             echo $row['Full_name'];
             $image= $row['profile'];
             echo $image;
    }
    }
}
```

Here is my Code. When I run it it just shows scrambled lines(!!)
What can I do to display the images which are saved as Longblob in mysql database.

This is a web-based project, coded in cpanel hosting. I tried some solutions but they didn't work. I think the problem happens in the links

I tried this solution:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode( $image ); ?>" />
```

Comment: have you tried this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111390/displaying-blob-image-from-mysql-database-into-dynamic-div-in-html/34112174

Comment: Dhaval Purohit, How can I use this in my code:.         echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($blob).'"/>';

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use blob to store images. Use varchar to save URL of the image and upload that images to specific folder. MySQL is not designed to store images.