# Use embedded image data multiple times in a single HTML

Tags: html, image, html-encode

Assume I want to have [embedded image data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2329364/1497199) in my html like this [example from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML):

```
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA
ANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4
//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU
5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

(which produces a red dot).

How can I re-use this same image data multiple times in the same HTML file?

```
<html>

<body>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA
ANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4
//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU
5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />

<h1>Some Content</h1>


<img src="???" alt="Another red dot"/><br>

<img src="???" alt="And so on..."/><br>



</body>
</html>
```

The overall goal is to create a self-contained (emailable) HTML file that can be opened and viewed independent of any network connectivity.  The images are relatively small thumbnails -- icons representing different divisions in the overall organization.  The content of the page is a list of items, each item has an icon.  Each specific icon is typically used multiple times in the page.

Comment: Given all the restrictions of email, I'd say the best option is just repeating that exact `<img>` tag you've got. The browser is smart enough to cache it, and you're not sending it constantly.